# How to call stored procedure with parameter type AnyData?

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

I'm trying to call a store procedure with `anyData` Parameter from .Net but i get an error due to the parameter:

*ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_SE_TEST'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored*

If I change the parameter in the procedure to varchar2 works fine but not with AnyData.

I have this procedure:

```
Procedure Sp_Se_Test(v_Param  In anydata,
                     v_out_result      Out Sys_Refcursor);
```

and the call from .net:

```
using (var cw = new OracleCommand{ Connection = db, CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                                                   CommandText = "PackageName.Sp_Se_Test"
                })
                {
                    cw.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "v_Param", OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2 , Value = "Testing" });
                    cw.Parameters.Add("v_out_result", OracleDbType.RefCursor,ParameterDirection.Output);

                    db.Open();
                    using (var dr = cw.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            var res = dr["Result"];
                        }
                        dr.Close();
                    }
                }
```

I think that is due to the OracleDbType but i don't know which is the type of AnyData.

Someone knows how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a few years since I've used Oracle, but my recollection is the you need to pass an empty DataSet as the object v_out_result will end up in when creating the parameter. Might be wrong though.

Comment: See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321718 - you don't use a DataReader as you are.

Comment: Looks like you use ODP.net. ODP is very sensitive. It needs to match to actual Oracle objects. If your ODP parameter is varchar2 your SP parameter better be varchar2. Oracle may support AnyData but ODP you using may be - not.

Comment: The problem not are related DataReader or how to retrieve the data, is related to v_Param DataType, if I change the procedure from anydata to varchar2 works fine.

Seems that T.S. says, ODP.net only support primitive datatypes but I'm not sure.

Comment: I didn't say that. Read exactly what I said. Datatype must match - this is what I said

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET does not support the PL/SQL ANYDATA datatype. (It cannot be bound to from ODP.NET). You will need to rewrite the procedure using a supported type or wrap the SP with a new one that uses PL/SQL to convert the type to something that is supported.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2171107